# Watch Reactions Trick Cache

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to implement a Reaction Role System on my Discord Bot. I read that the "on_reaction_add()" uses the bot cache, so old messages(messages before bot was booted) wont get monitored. I made a JSON File, which has the MessageID of the Message which contains the Reaction which i want to watch. Is there a way to push this message into the cache everytime the bot boots (for example in the on_ready() method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [on_raw_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction_add#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) instead, it will get called any time a reaction is added to any message, regardless of if it is in the cache.